# SQL2059W A device full warning - when trying to bring tablespace online

Tags: import, db2, backup, db2-luw

Trying to do a DB2 import as part of a system copy and the transaction logs filled up. Import was cancelled, transaction log backup ran, and number of logs were increased to approximately 90% of the available disk (previously 70%).

Restarted DB and kicked off DB but now that errors due to the tablespace state - running `db2 list tablespaces show detail` shows I have 4 tablespaces in Backup Pending state.

So I tried `db2 backup database <SID> tablespace <SID>#BTABI online` but I get the error:

> SQL2059W A device full warning was encountered on device "/db2/db2". Do you want to continue(c), terminate this device only(d), abort the utility(t) ? (c/d/t) t

No option works but to terminate.

The thing is, the device isn't full. There's no activities on the DB, running `db2 list applications` gives:

> SQL1611W No data was returned by Database System Monitor.

Running `db2 "select log_utilization_percent,dbpartitionnum from sysibmadm.log_utilization order by 2"` to show the log utilization returns 0.

There's no logs in use. The filesystem has space free. I even tried reducing the number of logs again to make sure but get the same issue.

I tried `db2 "alter tablespace <SID>#BTABI switch online"` instead and although this returns a 'success' statement it doesn't actually do anything - my tablespaces are still in Backup pending?

Any ideas please

Comment: Though you say the filesystem has free space, DB2 clearly thinks otherwise. Check `db2diag.log` around the time of the attempted backup for more details. Alternatively, you can `backup db BLAH to /dev/null` if you  have another backup that you can use in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to write the backup images to the `/db2/db2` file system, which doesn't have enough space to hold the backup image(s).

Note: When you execute `BACKUP DATABASE` as in your example above *without specifying where to send the backup* (i.e. you don't use the `to /dir/ectory` or another option like `use TSM`), DB2 will write the backup image to the current directory.  Make sure you specify **where** to store the backup image (and that it has enough free space to hold the backup image).  If you don't care about recoverability and are just trying to get the table space out of backup pending state, you can specify /dev/null as your location as @mustaccio suggests in the comments above.

Also:  You may want to look at the `COMMITCOUNT` option for the import utility so you're not trying to insert all data in a single massive transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the answers... it's set up to backup to CommVault and online backups had been disabled whilst we were doing the import, but transaction logs backups were still running and backing up there. None of the filesystems involved were full.

In the end I kicked off a full backup to a disk area that had enough space before I went to bed - it worked and it finally got out of Backup Pending state! 

Unfortunately I then hit a problem I'd seen before; 

SQL0668N  Operation not allowed for reason code "3" on table "SAPECD.BSIM".  SQLSTATE=57016 row=1
(DB) INFO: disconnected from DB

Comment: The fix I had for this previously was:

load from /dev/null of del terminate into SAPECD.BSIM

This time though, after running that on a number of tables, the import fails will:

BSIM deleted/truncated

I guess I need to get it to start a re-import from scratch on those tables but I'm not sure how...

Comment: Even if you are using CommVault for normal backups, the command you executed in your question will not write to CommVault – it will write to the file system. (This is unlike archive log files which may be configured to go directly to CommVault) When you use the `BACKUP DATABASE` command manually (instead of having CommVault trigger a backup for you), you would need to specify `load /<software_install_path>/Base/libDb2Sbt.so` in your command to tell DB2 to write the backup to CommVault.

Comment: Thanks Ian, yes you have a point - that command would have been trying to backup to a location in which indeed there wasn't space!
Anyway a full backup elsewhere cleared that. The 'new' 'truncated' error was my fault; I'd killed off the import early seeing the 'load pending' state error and artificially created a new error. Letting it run for the remaining packages (even if some failed) cleared this, so that some packages just failed with 'load pending' still. Seems I need to keep resetting the status and restarting the import, a percentage fails each time but it gradually works on more &more

Answer (score 0):

As per above comments  - just kept running the import, resetting the 'pending load' status each time with:

load from /dev/null of del terminate into SAPECD.

A few packages fail each time but the rest process. Letting finish, resetting again and restarting the import gets through a little more each time.